# Find characters inbetween two symbols using python without re

Tags: python, string

I need to print the characters between the ' '

```
import linecache
line = linecache.getline("sele4.py", 27)
print ((line))
text2 = line[line.find("\'")+1:line.find("\' ")]
print (text2)
```

Output:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Line A')]").click()

Line A')]").click()
```

Expected output:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Line A')]").click()

Line A
```

Along with 27th line of the file sele4.py I should get only "Line A", but am getting extra characters.Am new to it.Please correct me where I have gone wrong.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I am not sure what did not work for you ? Is it like `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Line A')]").text)` did not print anything ?

Comment: @cruisepandey "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Line A')]").text)" is a string.. From this string I need to print only Line A

Comment: @Dev could you not use `string.split("'")[1]`

Comment: When you print the above one what is the output that you get ?

Comment: @cruisepandey using "line.split("'")[1]"  I got the expected output.Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use the following on `text2` to strip out the `'` and later?

```
text = text2.split("'", 1)[0]
```

or better yet just do this from the beginning:

```
line.split("'")[1]
```

Explanation: `split("a")` splits the string into individual strings for each occurrence of `a`. For your use case my first example splits it to `["Line A", "')]\").click()"]`, and I use a subscript to choose the first element of the sequence.  Likewise, my second example splits your string into `["driver.find_element_by_xpath(\"//*[contains(text(), '", "Line A", "')]\").click()"]` and I use the subscript to get the second element of the sequence.

Comment: It worked! but could you please explain it

Comment: `split("a")` splits the string into individual strings for each occurrence of `a`. For your use case my first example splits it to `["Line A", "')]\").click()"]`, and I use a subscript to choose the first element of the sequence.  Likewise, my second example splits your string into `["driver.find_element_by_xpath(\"//*[contains(text(), '", "Line A", "')]\").click()"]` and I use the subscript to get the second element of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `start` of `str.find()` method.

```
line = linecache.getline("sele4.py", 27)
print(line)
first = line.find("\'")
next_ = line.find("\'", first + 1)
text = line[first+1:next_]
```